# Mapping existing tables to Domain classes in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dns

I don't even know if I'm using the correct terms but here goes:

Is there a way to map the tables and their relations in a SQL Server to domain (C# code) automatically, by means of a tool or something?

I've used the nhibernate plugin, but it creates a file in .cs and another in xml, that has the mapping, but I want that mapping to be present as "property" in the .cs file.

Sorry if this is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) or maybe [Linq2SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx), but I'm not familiar with how that works.

Tho, out of EF and NHibernate, I prefer NHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Use LLBLgen of Linq 2 Sql (available in VS 2008). Or use Entity Framework (in VS 2008 SP1).
Linq 2 sql allows you to drag and drop a table from sql server to the canvas and it creates a domain class for you with properties mapped to columns.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Fluent NHibernate and see if that is what you are looking for: 
http://blog.jagregory.com/2008/08/08/introducing-fluent-nhibernate/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Castle ActiveRecord](http://castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html) which uses attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read a bit about Linq to Sql

http://searchwindevelopment.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid8_gci1269859,00.html#

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com/).  It will generate your DAL and can also generates code off of custom templates.